# Solve by reduction for halting

Tags: logic

> Given an arbitrary Scheme program $P$ ,does there exist an input $I$ for $P$ such that $P$ halts when run with input $I$? Prove this is undecidable by reduction of halting problem.

Consider the program 
`halts? (P, I)`, which is undecidable by definition.

Call the required program `C (P)`, which **returns** the input $I$ for $P$ such that $P$ halts.

Thus we can define `halts` as:

```
def halts (P, I):
    if(C(P) == I) return true;
    else return false;
```

Therefore, we have shown the halting problem is decidable, contradiction.

Is this right?

Comment: The program $C$ you defined isn't the same as the program described in the question.  The program in the question only returns true or false, not the input.

Comment: Also, which halting problem is your book referring to?  Is it the one that says "Does every input to program P halt" or is it the one that says "Does input I on program P halt?" ?

Comment: @DanielV, "Does input I on program P halt?"

Comment: @DanielV, we can create a decider for `C` then right? That would also work?

Comment: The $C$ you defined is an unnecessary complication for this problem.  I suggest first try to understand the difference between the $C$ you defined and the oracle given in the question.

Comment: Here's a big hint for this problem:  in the body of $halts(P, I)$, consider construction of a program $Q$ that ignores its inputs.

Comment: @DanielV, okay lets say it ignores all inputs, then what should it run?

Comment: You considered my hint for less than 60 seconds.  That's...a remarkable lack of effort.

Comment: @DanielV, sorry let me think for a while... Lets create a program called $A$ that returns true if $P$ halts on $I$ and false otherwise. Dang it, I'm so stuck. This idea I just gave doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Your task is to fill in the dots:

$$\begin{array} {l}
\text{def halts(P, I):} \\
\quad \text{Q = ...} \\
\quad \text{if (C(Q)) ...} \\
\quad \text{else      ...} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @DanielV, I've spent a good amount of time thinking about this. We can let $Q$ halt if $I = 0$ else not. This solves the halting problem, contradiction?

Comment: @DanielV, so the idea with returning the input is correct?

Comment: I'd like to object to something that you wrote in your question. Namely, you say about the halting problem "..., which is undecidable by definition."  This isn't correct. The halting problem is not undecidable *by definition*. That is, the halting problem is not defined to be undecidable. Rather, it is a remarkable theorem, proved by Alan Turing, that the halting problem is undecidable.

Comment: No, because then Q is completely unrelated to P.